# django apache2 [wsgi:error] internal server error 500

Tags: python, django, apache2, wsgi

I've been stuck in this django apache deployment. When I try to access some pages my website keeps showing this 500 Internal Server error. and Some pages work well
i found this in error.log

These are the steps I followed

https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/Debian_Install_Django_Apache2.md

```
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177572 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] 
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177576 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177580 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] 
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177586 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177602 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 1027, in find_library
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177606 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     return parser.libraries[name]
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177617 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] KeyError: "'static'"
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177624 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] 
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177627 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177631 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] 
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177636 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177715 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 131, in __call__
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177722 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177729 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177741 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     response = self._middleware_chain(request)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177748 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 57, in inner
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177753 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177758 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177763 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     response = handle_uncaught_exception(
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177768 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 185, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177772 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     return callback(request)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177778 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/src/helpers/views.py", line 15, in error500
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177782 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     return render(request, 'error-500.html')
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177788 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177792 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177798 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177802 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177807 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 15, in get_template
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177812 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     return engine.get_template(template_name)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177818 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 34, in get_template
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177822 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177828 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 175, in get_template
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177832 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177839 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 157, in find_template
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177843 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177850 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loaders/cached.py", line 57, in get_template
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177861 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     template = super().get_template(template_name, skip)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177868 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py", line 28, in get_template
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177872 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     return Template(
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177878 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 154, in __init__
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177882 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177888 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 200, in compile_nodelist
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177892 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     return parser.parse()
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177898 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 513, in parse
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177902 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     raise self.error(token, e)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177907 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 511, in parse
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177911 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177916 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 1089, in load
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177920 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     lib = find_library(parser, name)
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177926 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]   File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 1029, in find_library
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177930 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712]     raise TemplateSyntaxError(
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177944 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: ''static'' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177948 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] account
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177951 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] admin_list
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177955 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] admin_modify
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177958 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] admin_urls
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177961 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] cache
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177964 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] i18n
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177967 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] l10n
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177971 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] log
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177974 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] socialaccount
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177983 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] static
[Wed Feb 22 09:01:49.177986 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 99825:tid 140583099365056] [remote 152.89.196.211:60712] tz
```

Answer (score 0):

the error message looks like you have a typo in a html template like

correct

```
{% load static %}
```

wrong

```
{% load 'static' %}
```